# Firebase, google clould and dev. console issues

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, logging, firebase, console

The issue with loading page forever or getting an blank firebase console in chrome is solved. Working fine now.

Issue in google cloud console
[image: google cloud console loading]

Issue in developer console:
[image: developer console 3 dot loading]

Blank page in firebase console:
[image: firebase console script errors]

I check the status of firebase console (all green) and i check the javascript logs

> Refused to load the script 'about:blank' because it violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'
>   'unsafe-inline' https://*.google.com https://*.gstatic.com
>   https://feedback.googleusercontent.com
>   https://www.googletagmanager.com https://*.googleapis.com
>   https://www.googleadservices.com https://*.google-analytics.com
>   https://*.doubleclick.net 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src' was
>   not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
>
> [IH] bootstraping for https://console.firebase.google.com/ [IH]
>   Starting extension. [IH] Browser type: chrome [IH] Browser version:
>   51.0.2704.106 '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL='
>   instead. [IH] Local storage works. [IH] This is not a hotel site,
>   skipping [IH] Vertical priority 0 ready to go hidden [IH] This is not
>   a travel operator, skipping [IH] Vertical priority 1 ready to go
>   hidden [IH] This is not a rental site, skipping [IH] Vertical priority
>   2 ready to go hidden Error: Sf
>       at Error (native)
>       at PAN_cX.$get ([https://www.gstatic.com/*/pantheon/*/js/k=pantheon.mobilesdk_module_set.pt_](https://www.gstatic.com/_/pantheon/_/js/k=pantheon.mobilesdk_module_set.pt_)…sole_main/am=fgCAAg/rt=j/d=1/rs=ADqnUbOhUHgf90Puyf-Xe4TNDpCVZ8n4fw:6201:64)
>       at Object.invoke (third_party/javascript/angular/v1_5/angular.min.js:41:376)
>       at eval (third_party/javascript/angular/v1_5/angular.min.js:43:175)
>       at d (third_party/javascript/angular/v1_5/angular.min.js:40:344)
>       at e (third_party/javascript/angular/v1_5/angular.min.js:41:78)
>       at Object.instantiate (third_party/javascript/angular/v1_5/angular.min.js:41:445)
>       at PAN_eX.$get ([https://www.gstatic.com/*/pantheon/*/js/k=pantheon.mobilesdk_module_set.pt_](https://www.gstatic.com/_/pantheon/_/js/k=pantheon.mobilesdk_module_set.pt_)…ole_main/am=fgCAAg/rt=j/d=1/rs=ADqnUbOhUHgf90Puyf-Xe4TNDpCVZ8n4fw:6203:100)
>       at Object.invoke (third_party/javascript/angular/v1_5/angular.min.js:41:376)
>       at eval (third_party/javascript/angular/v1_5/angular.min.js:43:175)

How can i solve this issue? Do i need to remove all projects and start again? There is any relation to gmail quota? What is wrong?

The first log line related to blank page script show because i have Momentum plugin (My new tab is a nice quote on top of a nice photo). The other chrome plugins i have are:

- Lastpass
- Firebug Lite
- Responsive Inspector
- Awesome Screenshot
- PageSpeed Ins
- JSlint for chrome
- Google Spaces
- Momentum

I notice that i can use firebase console in mozilla firefox without problem, so i continue the development there.

Comment: The console is now working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with loading page forever or getting an blank firebase console in chrome is solved. Working fine now.